# how to split an alphanumeric string into an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having an alphanumeric string

```
t14u1e7f8h15j4m3n50o65r22q29
```

I would like to transform this string into an array,in order to save space I have purposely made it that way.,Now the issue i'm facing right now is that in order to tranform it into an array using php , the order be like

```
data: [14, 1, 7, 8, ..]

categories : [t,u,e,f,h,j,m,n,o]
```

also is it possible to further transform categories into:

```
categories : [20:00,21:00,5:00,f,h,j,m,n,o]

where a => 1:00
      b => 2:00
```

also since the order is like t,u,e,f,h,j is it possible to arrange them alphabetically maximum of 10 characters i.e
`categories [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,i,j,k]` that is 10 hours from current time..

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: For your first step, use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). Also don't know how you're saving space here. By coming up with this non-standard data format, you're creating computation overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(I assume that you only use lowercase letters)

```
<?php

    $string = "t14u1e7f8h15j4m3n50o65r22q29";
    $result = array("data" => array(), "categories" => array(), "categories" => array());


    preg_match_all("/\d+/", $string, $matches);
    $result["data"] = $matches[0];
    preg_match_all("/[^\d+]/", $string, $matches);
    $result["categories"] = $matches[0];

    foreach($result["categories"] as $v) {
        $result["categories2"][] = ord(strtolower($v))-96;
    }

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 8
            [4] => 15
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 3
            [7] => 50
            [8] => 65
            [9] => 22
            [10] => 29
        )

    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => t
            [1] => u
            [2] => e
            [3] => f
            [4] => h
            [5] => j
            [6] => m
            [7] => n
            [8] => o
            [9] => r
            [10] => q
        )

    [categories2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 21
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 8
            [5] => 10
            [6] => 13
            [7] => 14
            [8] => 15
            [9] => 18
            [10] => 17
        )

)
```

Comment: I think the question would prefer to end with array_combine($result['categories'], $result['data']); to get a single array with the categories as keys and data as values.

Comment: @kainaw OP has to tell that, but i can't see that in the question also the last part i don't get every thing